# Moving a Asp.net WebApp on SQL Server To MySQL what are the potential Issues?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, web-applications

The WebApp makes use of Asp.net membership, And roles with session. it also uses LLBLGen Pro as a datalayer.

My Question is what are the potential issues that might make this not work ?

Comment: Potential issues are numerous, it's the same as asking what can happen if we transplant a heart from human A to human B. List of things that can go wrong are huge, it's not a simple drop in replacement thing.

Comment: yeah I know but what would your biggest worry personally be

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL have their own specifics when it comes to SQL or storing data (physically). Many applications use those. For example, MySQL has `INSERT IGNORE` statement, SQL server allows you to define clustering indexes and the list goes on. My worry would be that the queries wouldn't work and that the ASP app uses SQL extensions available to SQL server that MySQL doesn't have. Basically, I'd worry if the thing would give my app any data or not.

Comment: This question can not be answered. Any answer would require writing a book. The issues are endless, because MySQL and SQL-server are worlds apart.

Comment: @johan we are using a data abstraction layer mapper which supports mySQL so i dont think you could fill a book with the problems as most transact stuff doesn't have to be modified, but i have written 4 pages on potential problems, yes NB you are on the right track as its more the loss of certain features im concerned about, as it is I'm happy asp.net membership is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of the potential issues that come to mind:

- Security, users, groups/roles
- Transactional semantics and boundaries
- Porting existing stored procedures, functions, CLR code, etc.
- Data type compatibility / semantics
- Performance and scalability (each DB has its own areas of strengths and weaknesses)
- Error reporting and recovery
- Handling dynamic SQL
- Lack of step-in debugging from ASP.NET to the DB with MySql
- Database schema change management
- Support for fulltext search
- Differences in SQL queries and commands
- Tool support: SQL profiler, Visual Studio T-SQL editor, etc.
- Driver support
- Multiple active result sets (if needed)
- Async command support

I'm sure there's more...